# How to reference 32bit integer data in a 64 bit dump

Tags: windbg, sos

If I have a System.Int32 at a known memory address of a 64-bit .Net process dump, how can I reference its data in a condition or expression in windbg?  For example:

`? poi(000000ba2e4de938) == 0n27` is displaying as 0 instead of 1, even though I *know* that the value at that address is 27 (`dt int 000000ba2e4de938` displays 0n27).  It is doing so, because it picks up 32 junk bits after the value I am attempting to access, since poi grabs pointer-sized data.

Is there a way to grab data of a certain size to use within expressions?  I have so far only found ways to dump the data, but not use it within expressions or conditions.

Comment: Maybe mask the high bits  ?  Poi($$$$) & 0x00000000ffffffff

Comment: Or maybe use dt ((large_intxxx *) poi())->lowpart

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: use `dwo(...)` for 32 bits, `qwo(...)` for 64 bits and `poi(...)` for architecture dependent size.

Long answer:

Let's look at an Int32 with SOS first:

```
0:014> .symfix
0:014> .reload
0:014> .loadby sos clr
0:006> !name2ee *!System.Int32
Module:      000007feecab1000
Assembly:    mscorlib.dll
Token:       00000000020000f0
MethodTable: 000007feed1603d0
EEClass:     000007feecb71810
Name:        System.Int32
[...]
0:006> !dumpheap -mt 000007feed1603d0
         Address               MT     Size
00000000028376d8 000007feed1603d0       24 

0:006> !do 00000000028376d8 
Name:        System.Int32
MethodTable: 000007feed1603d0
EEClass:     000007feecb71810
Size:        24(0x18) bytes
File:        C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll
Fields:
              MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr            Value Name
000007feed1603d0  400055f        8         System.Int32  1 instance             8868 m_value
```

From that output, you can see that the value (`m_value`) of the Int32 is at the address of the object + an offset of 8.

The length of Int32 is 32 bit, so we need the `dd` (dump DWORD) to look at the memory:

```
0:006> dd 00000000028376d8+8 L1
00000000`028376e0  000022a4
```

Convert that into decimal and it'll be what has been displayed by SOS before:

```
0:006> ? 22a4
Evaluate expression: 8868 = 00000000`000022a4
```

To use it in a condition, use `dwo` (DWORD size) instead of `poi` (pointer size, which is `qwo` on 64 bits):

```
0:006> ? dwo(00000000028376d8+8)
Evaluate expression: 8868 = 00000000`000022a4
```

Comment: dwo() was the ticket!  Do you happen to know of a good reference that would have included that?  It's not one listed and explained on http://windbg.info/doc/1-common-cmds.html or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540507(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @DannyMeister: well, in WinDbg's help file, things are sometimes hard to find. This particular info is available at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552157(v=vs.85).aspx